# How to display MySQL "result" object to user with express-handlebars?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I currently have a query in my node js that looks like this:

```
app.get('/fav/books', function(req, res){
var sql = ("SELECT title, pictureUrl, author, description, genre FROM books")
  connection.query(sql, function(err, result){
    if(err) {
      console.log('Error in the query.');
    } else {
      console.log('Success!\n');
      console.log(result);
      var book = result;
      return book;
    }
  });
});
```

And outputs to console like this:
[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4Lud.png)

I want to "return book;" to the user with handlebars in a sort of card output like this:

```
<div class="page-carousel">
  <div class="panel id1">
    <img href="pictureUrl"/>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p><strong>author</strong></p>
    <p>description</p>
    <p>genre</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The panel would be the ID of the Book as it needs to create as many panels as there are IDs. The book information would be as is.

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs is just perfect for this. Assign this response object to a $scope variable say $books.Then you could do this:

```
<div class="page-carousel">
  <div ng-repeat="x in books" class="panel {{x.id}}">
    <img href="{{x.pictureUrl}}"/>
    <h3>{{x.title}}</h3>
    <p><strong>{{x.author}}</strong></p>
    <p>{{x.description}}</p>
    <p>{{x.genre}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I can see the books you are returning is an array of objects, each object containing a book info in this case we need to iterate in a loop in handlebars like -

```
{{#each book}}
  <div class="page-carousel">
    <div class="panel id1">
      <img href={{book.pictureUrl}}/>
      <h3>{{book.title}}</h3>
      <p><strong>{{book.author}}</strong></p>
      <p>{{book.description}}</p>
      <p>{{book.genre}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: This didn't work. I think there has to be something rendered or a helper with handlebars to allow "book" to get to the home.handlebars page.